# Ruby Installation problem or something else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I cannot call:

`bundle install` or `bundle update`

on Windows 7 SP1. I get the following error even with DevKit installed and WORKING!

> bundle update Fetching source index
>   for http://rubygems.org/ Using
>   addressable (2.2.6) Using daemons
>   (1.1.4) Installing hiredis (0.3.2)
>   with native extensions
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/
>   1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:551:in `rescue in block in build_extensions':
>   ERROR:  Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>   (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
>
> ```
>     C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -c
> ```
>
> -O3 -fPIC -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings
>       -g -ggdb  net.c net.c:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all
>   code is position independent)
>   net.c:35:24: fatal error:
>   sys/socket.h: No such file or
>   directory compilation terminated.
>   make: *** [net.o] Error 1 creating
>   Makefile
>
> make C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby -e "puts
>   'EXPORTS', 'Init_hiredis_ext'"  >
>   hiredis_ext-i386- mingw32.def gcc -I.
>   -IC:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32
>   -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1 .9.1/ruby/backward
>   -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unu sed-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-fiel d-initializers -Wno-long-long
>   -IC:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/hiredis-0.3.
>   2/vendor/hiredis  -o connection.o -c
>   connection.c connection.c:1:24: fatal
>   error: sys/socket.h: No such file or
>   directory compilation terminated.
>   make: *** [connection.o] Error 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/hiredis-0
>   .3.2 for inspection. Results logged to
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/hiredis-0.3.2/ext/hiredis_
>   ext/gem_make.out
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:529:in
>   `b lock in build_extensions'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:504:in`
>   e ach'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:504:in
>   `b uild_extensions'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:180:in`
>   i nstall'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/sour
>   ce.rb:101:in `block in install'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/ruby
>   gems_integration.rb:78:in`
>   preserve_paths'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/sour
>   ce.rb:91:in `install'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/inst
>   aller.rb:58:in`block (2 levels) in
>   run'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/ruby
>   gems_integration.rb:93:in
>   `with_build_args'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/inst
>   aller.rb:57:in`block in run'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec
>   _set.rb:12:in `block in each'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec
>   _set.rb:12:in`each'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec
>   _set.rb:12:in `each'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/inst
>   aller.rb:49:in`run'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/inst
>   aller.rb:8:in `install'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/cli.
>   rb:270:in`update'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vend
>   or/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vend
>   or/thor/invocation.rb:118:in`
>   invoke_task'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vend
>   or/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vend
>   or/thor/base.rb:389:in`start'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/bin/bundle:13:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in`load'
>           from C:/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `'

Comment: There is a similar report on Github (https://github.com/pietern/hiredis-rb/issues/1), perhaps that helps a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure this is a bundler problem, and not the gems you are trying to install?

create a Gemfile with a very simple set of requirments, like this one:

```
source: rubygems
gem 'rake'
```

and run `bundle install` on this, to see what happens.

also - if your trying to get a rails environment up and running, you should be using http://railsinstaller.org - it will make your life so much easier.

Comment: Yeah the problem is with the gems. I am going back to Ubuntu. Thanks